# Can it be proven no polynomial algorithm exists for an NP-Complete prob.?

Tags: np-complete, np, np-hard

I can't really seem to grasp what it really means to say a problem is NP-Complete. Could anyone help me with the following question?

*An NP-complete problem is a problem for which one can prove that an algorithm for solving it in polynomial time does not exist. Is the statement true?*

I would want to say this statement isn't true, because can anyone *actually* prove that such an algorithm doesn't exist for any NP-Complete problem? From looking around on various sources, I understand that no polynomial time algorithm *is known* for any NP-Complete problem; however, it can't be proven.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem

Comment: It is one of the millenium questions. If it could be proven, someone would be a million dollars richer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in some situations to prove that no algorithm exists that is better than a certain limit.

For example the `O(n log n)` bound for a comparison sort has been [proven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list). No matter how clever we become in the future, we can be sure that no-one will ever invent an `O(n)` comparison sort.

In this case though, no-one has found a proof. But that doesn't mean it can't be proven.

Comment: This seems like a good argument to use for this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The statement is more fundamentally wrong: There are problems that cannot be solved in polynomial time which are much harder than NP problems. The point of NP completeness is a polynomial time solution existing is equivalent to P=NP (which means additionally that a solution not existing means P!=NP).